# speed up MyISAM inserts

Tags: mysql

It takes a lot of time to restore data from a mysqldump file.
Is there any parameter that I can change dynamically to speed up the inserts of MyISAM only data without restarting mysql instance?

Comment: Restoring MyISAM from a dump file is generally pretty quick, it's InnoDB where it gets quite a bit slower. How long is 'a lot of time' and how big is the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a job for `bulk_insert_buffer_size`

According to the MySQL Documentation on [**bulk_insert_buffer_size**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_bulk_insert_buffer_size)

> MyISAM uses a special tree-like cache to make bulk inserts faster for
>   INSERT ... SELECT, INSERT ... VALUES (...), (...), ..., and LOAD DATA
>   INFILE when adding data to nonempty tables. This variable limits the
>   size of the cache tree in bytes per thread. Setting it to 0 disables
>   this optimization. The default value is 8MB.

Try raising this to 256M

Restart of MySQL not required. Just run:

```
SET GLOBAL bulk_insert_buffer_size = 1024 * 1024 * 256;
```

Please remember to add it to `my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
bulk_insert_buffer_size=256M
```

The, you can reload the mysqldump.

Give it a Try !!!